# How do logging frameworks/libraries work?

Tags: logging

For example, log4j has logging levels, INFO, DEBUG etc. When I say `LOG_DEBUG (some message)`, will the log4j code check every time if the log_level is set to DEBUG, then if yes log the message?

If yes and if my code has a thousand LOG_DEBUG statements then `isDebugLevel()` is checked a thousand times.

I believe I am asking a basic question, so I am sorry if it is annoying, but I could not find answers on the web.

Comment: So what if it checks, this most of the time a simple trivial is x < y...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. All loggers I am aware of will check the logging level each time a logging event occurs.

This is a simple check, so it should have no significant performance impact.